# trying to run 'rails g controller App' on OS X, i get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm trying to run rails g controller app and I receive this error in terminal
also no 'rails ----' commands work they all receive this error

here

```
em install minitest
    WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.3, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
    Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.dylib': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0.dylib, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.dylib': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.dylib, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0.so, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.dylib': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0.so.dylib, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-3': dlopen(libgtk-3, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-3.dylib': dlopen(libgtk-3.dylib, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-3.so.0': dlopen(libgtk-3.so.0, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-3.so.0.dylib': dlopen(libgtk-3.so.0.dylib, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-3.so': dlopen(libgtk-3.so, 13): image not found.
    Could not open library 'libgtk-3.so.dylib': dlopen(libgtk-3.so.dylib, 13): image not found
```

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901400/warning-nokogiri-was-built-against-libxml-version-2-7-7-but-has-dynamically-lo

Answer (score 0):

try gem uninstall nokogiri then gem install nokogiri. Or try gem update nokogiri. Also, try looking at this post [Image Not Found Errors after Upgrade to Rails 3.1, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040502/image-not-found-errors-after-upgrade-to-rails-3-1-how-to-fix) .

Comment: still get the error: 
'WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.3, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0, 13): image not found.'

Comment: still receive Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0': dlopen(libgtk-x11-2.0, 13): image not found.

Comment: also nothing to update